# nginx proxy_pass not serving static files

Tags: proxypass

I have this conf:

```
server {
   listen 81;
   server_name test.example.com;
   default_type  application/octet-stream;
   auth_basic "Restricted";
   auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;


   location / {
           proxy_pass      http://192.168.0.2:8080/main/;
           include       mime.types;
           proxy_redirect off;
           }
  location /static {
           proxy_pass      http://192.168.0.2:8080/main/;
           include       mime.types;
           proxy_redirect off;
           }
}
```

When I load in browser `test.example.com` I get no static files, no css, no .js

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you have a server listening on port 8080?

Comment: And what do, you get when trying to load static content? what is the error code, if there is one?

Comment: Yes, on 192.168.0.2 there is a tornado listening on 8080.
If I load http://192.168.0.2:8080/main/ everything is ok

Comment: Any messages in the logs?

Comment: on 192.168.0.2 logs I get:

`2016-04-22 11:27:03: WARNING: 404 GET /main//rpiserver_styles.css?v=968b1e3c3e01081713f7b1a173b4f2ba (192.168.0.199) 17.52ms
2016-04-22 11:27:03: WARNING: 404 GET /main//jquery-ui-1.10.3.trontastic.css?v=a470e5b1111f1b7f54c5f174fff44061 (192.168.0.199) 9.21ms
2016-04-22 11:27:03: WARNING: 404 GET /main//webfont.css?v=f3445b0c1de9364e3eeca03f7d0c3278 (192.168.0.199) 9.13ms
2016-04-22 11:27:03: WARNING: 404 GET /main//jquery-1.10.2.min.js?v=628072e7212db1e8cdacb22b21752cda (192.168.0.199) 9.13ms`

192.168.0.199 is an nginx with auth_basic and proxy_pass

Comment: on proxy 162.168.0.199 error log I get:
`2016/04/22 14:26:59 [error] 10617#0: *158366 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/static/master_increment_sn.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 82.**.***.***, server: test.example.com, request: "GET /static/master_increment_sn.js?v=151942f1a8f51b458ea343bf127e2355 HTTP/1.1", host: "test.example.com", referrer: "http://test.example.com/"
`

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this today.

As far as I can tell, proxy_pass happens AFTER all the location directives are handled.

What I had to do was make sure I did not have any location directives anywhere else in my config.  Once I removed those and restarted my requests started to proxy correctly.

I removed: 
location ~* .(?:ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$

I had quite a few files that were being included in my nginx.conf that had "location" directives.